# All links don't work unless I open them in a new tab

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, permalinks

I have a website built on Exploring WordPress theme on a subdirectory of my main website. The problem is all links *don't redirect unless I right-click and open them in a new tab*. I tried to deactivate all the plugins, but nothing.

The exact same theme is installed on another host and works properly, I'm attaching chrome console,
BTW I tried Chrome on the desktop, IE on the desktop, then Chrome on my mobile, but the same problem.

[image]

UPDATE : jump to top button works, but links don't, `<a>` tag is defined properly, but doesn't work.
I switched to Twenty Fifteen theme and the problem disappeared, but it work on the exact same theme installed on another host.

Comment: try to give link by https

Comment: I did so, but the same problem, thanks for replying

Comment: even tho I don't have ssl certificate, my main domain is www.kamalbella.com , the problem is on www.kamalbella.com/horizon

Comment: all menu link is also not working for admin >?

Comment: no, no link works

Comment: did you tried by changing code of htaccess

Comment: I deleted it and generated a new one by wp permalinks, I also renamed .htaccess to .htaccessOLD for the root directory to avoid any conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this JQuery code in your footer part and then check.

```
<script>    
   $('a').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = link;
   })
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I tried it but the same problem

Comment: this fixed it :
<script>   
   jQuery('a').click(function(){
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = link;
   });
</script><script>   
   jQuery('a').click(function(){
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = link;
   });
</script>

I'm marking your answer as true, thank you very much

Comment: Okay great :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is working on new tab. So I think it is javascript issue, may be some pluging's js conflict.

So you should try to disable plugins one by one and tried to check which plugin cause this issue.

or

Disable all plugins you have and then theme to narrow down the cause. If disabling a plugin or reverting the theme fixes it, then you have found your culprit.

Comment: that's what I thought but I deactivated all plugins and I still have the same problem, thanks for replying

Comment: I changed the theme to twenty fifteen and the problem disappeared, but the same theme file is installed on another host and works properly